# subdomain gives 500 Internal Server Error for yii

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, yii

I have a **main website** xyz.org **written in cake php** which has *below .htaccess* rules. When I try to access the sub-domain it gives "500 Internal server errors" even if I had placed only index.php at sub domain directory.

Below is the .htaccess of the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 php_value max_execution_time 259200
</IfModule>
```

> I have main domain website in cakephp framework and sub domain in yii.

Comment: what is it? Yii or CakePHP?